# Populate multiple slide view with nested dictionary SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

My data models are like this:

```
struct Country: Hashable, Identifiable, Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let name: String?
    let states: [States]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case id, name, states
    }
}

struct States: Hashable, Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let name: String?
    let cities: [City]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
       case id, name, cities
    } 
}

struct City: Hashable, Codable {
    let id: Int?
    let name: String?
}
```

I have a slideView like this:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SlidingTab: View {

// Internal state to keep track of the selection index
@State private var selectionState: Int = 0 {
    didSet {
        selection = selectionState
    }
}

// Binding the selection index which will  re-render the consuming view
@Binding var selection: Int

// The title of the tabs
private var tabs: [String?]

init(selection: Binding<Int>, tabs: [String?]) {
    self._selection = selection
    self.tabs = tabs
}

var body: some View {
    VStack {
        ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false) {
            HStack(spacing: 24) {
                ForEach(self.tabs, id: \.self) { tab in
                    VStack {
                        Text(tab ?? "")
                            .frame(maxHeight: 55)
                            .font(.custom(Constant.Fonts.Futura, size: 15))
                            .foregroundColor(self.selection == self.tabs.firstIndex(of: tab) ? Constant.Colors.appColor : Color.black.opacity(0.5))
                        
                        Rectangle()
                            .frame(maxHeight: 3)
                            .foregroundColor(self.selection == self.tabs.firstIndex(of: tab) ? Constant.Colors.appColor : Color.clear)
                        
                    }
                    .fixedSize()
                    .onTapGesture {
                        withAnimation {
                            let selection = self.tabs.firstIndex(of: tab) ?? 0
                            self.selectionState = selection
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .padding(.horizontal, 20)
        }
    }
    
}
}
```

My View is like below:

```
import SwiftUI

struct SearchScreen: View {

// These should come from model
var countries = ["country1", "country2", "country3", "country4", "country5", "country6"]
var states = ["state1", "state2", "state3", "state4", "state5", "state6"]
var cities = ["city1", "city2", "city3", "city4", "city5", "city6"]

@State private var selectedCountryIndex = 0
@State private var selectedStateIndex = 1
@State private var selectedCityIndex = 2

var body: some View {
    ScrollView {
        Rectangle()
            .frame(height: 320)
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
        
        SlidingTab(selection: $selectedCountryIndex, tabs: countries)
            .onChange(of: selectedCountryIndex, perform: { value in
                print("selectedCountryIndex:\(self.selectedCountryIndex)")
            })
        
        SlidingTab(selection: $selectedStateIndex, tabs: states)
            .onChange(of: selectedStateIndex, perform: { value in
                print("selectedStateIndex:\(self.selectedStateIndex)")
            })
        
        SlidingTab(selection: $selectedCityIndex, tabs: cities)
            .onChange(of: selectedStateIndex, perform: { value in
                print("selectedStateIndex:\(self.selectedStateIndex)")
            })

    }
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.top)
}
}
```

I want to achieve when country is selected relevant states will be shown and when state is selected relevant cities will be shown, like below image. I tried multiple ways but could not achieve it. Any help would be much appreciated. You can get the json file from this link if you wish:

[json data](https://www.kaggle.com/datasets/tanweerulhaque/countries-states-cities-dataset)

[image]